# How to customize seam 3 credentials?

Tags: cdi, seam3

is there any way to customize seam 3 credentials object?

I need to add one more attribute to credentials (captcha). I tryed the following code:

```
@Named("credentials") @SessionScoped
public class Credentials extends CredentialsImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4377742708407292709L;

    private String captcha;

    public String getCaptcha() {
        return captcha;
    }

    public void setCaptcha(String captcha) {
         this.captcha = captcha;
    }

}
```

But it has a conflict with org.jboss.seam.security.CredentialsImpl @Named annotation. How can i override the credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yould could try a [CDI specialization](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/specialization.html).  Ie :

```
@Alternative 
@Specializes 
@SessionScoped
public class Credentials extends CredentialsImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4377742708407292709L;

    private String captcha;

    public String getCaptcha() {
        return captcha;
    }

    public void setCaptcha(String captcha) {
         this.captcha = captcha;
    }

}
```